# I want to prove that $\lim_{n\to +\infty }\frac{1}{n^{p}}=0$ for $0<p<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that $\lim_{n\to +\infty }\frac{1}{n^{p}}=0$ for $0<p<\infty$.

> [image: definition used in proofstrong text]

Please it's my first time so bear with my presentation.

so I attempted this by saying $$|S_n -s|<\epsilon$$
$$ |\frac{1}{n^{p}}-0|<\epsilon$$
$$ \frac{1}{n^{p}}<\epsilon$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^p<{\epsilon}$$
$$\frac{1}{n}<\sqrt[p]{\epsilon}$$
thus $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[p]{\epsilon}}<n$$ therefore for all N>n $$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{1}{n^{p}}=0$$
does this make sense?

Comment: Are you sure that $1/n^p =\sqrt[p]{1/n}$? I belive $1/n^p =n^{-p}$.

Comment: sorry i have corrected it now i used $\frac{1}{n^p}=\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^p$

Comment: What is your choice for $N$ corresponding to a given $\epsilon$?

Comment: since i want N to be larger than n I will choose N=$\frac{1}{\sqrt[p]{\epsilon}}+1$

Comment: Take the integer part of it since you want $N$ to be an integer.

Comment: so i can use the ceiling function of $\frac{1}{\sqrt[p]{\epsilon}}$ plus 1?

Comment: Yes, I would apply the ceiling function to make sure that the value of $N$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct. Well done!

But at the end you should specify that for every $\varepsilon >0$, let $N=\frac {1} {\sqrt[p]{\varepsilon}}$. Then conclude that for all $n>N$ we have that $|\frac 1 {n^p}-0|<\varepsilon$ and thus $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 {n^p}=0$$

You should also note that whether you have proved yet if the $p^{th}$ root of every number exists or not as that is a major part of your proof. It is indeed true but usually sequences are introduced before functions and thus you might not be allowed to use the fact that the $p^{th}$ root of every non-negative number exists.

But apart from that, everything looks good.

Comment: ok thank you very much